# if message found in specific channel Discord.net

Tags: .net, discord.net

Hello i try to get Notification if message founded in Specific Channel ID using (onmsg function). (while bot running)

my code.

```
  If message.Source = MessageSource.Bot Then
        'ignore
    Else

        Dim msg As String = message.Content

        If message.Content.Contains("hello") Then


            If discord.Channel.id = "123456789" Then

                'send message by bot to the channel
                'Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Sended in correcctly channel")

                'get notification

                MessageBox.Show("Sended in correcctly channel")

            End If

        End If
    End If
```

[problem i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hf0z.png)

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   BC30456 'Channel' is not a member of 'DiscordSocketClient'. Test C:\Users\diana\Desktop\1\Test\Test\Form1.vb    125 Active

Comment: Hi Diana! Can you please include the error you're experiencing or the specific question you have in your post?

Comment: @EvanM Done. (when i run the bot, if "hello" found in specific channel id "123456789" then will show me message.show, updated the post

Comment: Your `discord` variable is an instance of `DiscordSocketClient`, which when you think about it, makes logical sense why `Channel` does not exist. How can you get a channel from potentially thousands of channels that the client potentially has access to? In this case, you're looking for `message.Channel`, not `discord.Channel`.

Comment: @StillH., Thanks it worked, can you post it as answered question,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment of the thread, `discord` refers to OP's `DiscordSocketClient`, which in turn would refer to the current bot client; as such, a single object of `Channel` cannot possibly exist, as the bot may have access to more than a handful of "channels" within the reach of the bot.

OP was likely referring to the channel of which the message arrived in was, which would be `message.Channel`.

Additionally, it is worth noting that when determining the channel type, there could be several variants when using Discord.Net due to its [polymorphic nature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism) (e.g. a channel can be a voice, category, text channel and more; see [glossary](https://docs.stillu.cc/faq/misc/glossary.html#channel-types) for more details).

Although in the context of OP's code, only `ISocketMessageChannel` or its implementation is possible since a message could only be sent to a message channel. Despite this, the reason for bringing this up is that many more methods of obtaining a channel could sometimes return an `IChannel` only, leaving confusion behind as to why they could not send a message to this channel. When in fact, they only needed to (try) cast the channel as the appropriate type (see glossary above).